# How to calculate distance between two location by road?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to calculate distance between two locations by road/like driving mode.
Here is my code but error is coming at "response = client.execute(httppost);" this line.Please help me.

```
private double getDistance(double latFrom, double lngFrom,double latTo,double lngTo) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String apikey="API KEY";
    Double dist = 0.0;
    try {


        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + latFrom + "," + lngFrom + "&destination=" + latTo + "," + lngTo + "&mode=driving&sensor=false"+"&key="+apikey;

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


        response = client.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {

        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
        JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
        JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
        Log.i("Distance", distance.toString());
        dist = Double.parseDouble(distance.getString("text").replaceAll("[^\\.0123456789]","") );

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dist;
}
```

Comment: Do we have to guess, what the error is? Please provide the error you get

Comment: may be you are calling this method on wrong thread.

Comment: its giving error as  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142)

Comment: Call your request from a background thread like an AsyncTask or Runnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your error would be to perform all network operations on a background thread. For example, using `AsyncTask` or `Runnable` on a separate thread from the main.

To elaborate more on my answer, your network call would be performed in the `doInBackground()` method of your `AsyncTask`.

NEVER perform network operations on the main thread because network calls are blocking operations and would severely hinder your UI responsiveness.